# Android setText String won't persist after being set to textview and leaving the activity

Tags: android

I can fire the intent,choose the image and set the path in the target TextView. My issue is when I press the save menu button in the alarm details and return back to the details activity the SetText is gone. I need the SetText to stay or commit when save button is pressed so it can be used as a reference in my broadcastreciver.

Thanks to anyone who can help.

Relevant code:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    Intent intent = new Intent();

    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.setType("image/*");
    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Uri targetUri = data.getData();
        txtPictureSelection.setText("  " + getPathFromUri_managedQuery(targetUri));
        txtPictureSelection.setText("   " + getPathFromUri_CursorLoader(targetUri));
    }
}

//using deprecated managedQuery() method 
private String getPathFromUri_managedQuery(Uri uri) {
    String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, //selection
            null, //selectionArgs
            null //sortOrder
    );

    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();

    return cursor.getString(column_index);
}

//using CursorLoader() method for API level 11 or higher
private String getPathFromUri_CursorLoader(Uri uri) {

    String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

    CursorLoader cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(getApplicationContext(), uri, projection, null, //selection
            null, //selectionArgs
            null //sortOrder
    );

    Cursor cursor = cursorLoader.loadInBackground();

    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();

    return cursor.getString(column_index);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.alarm_details, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch(item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home: {
        finish();
        break;
    }
    case R.id.action_save_alarm_details: {
        updateModelFromLayout();

        AlarmManagerHelper.cancelAlarms(this);

        if(alarmDetails.id < 0) {
            dbHelper.createAlarm(alarmDetails);
        }
        else {
            dbHelper.updateAlarm(alarmDetails);
        }

        AlarmManagerHelper.setAlarms(this);

        setResult(RESULT_OK);
        finish();
    }
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private void updateModelFromLayout() {
    alarmDetails.timeMinute = timePicker.getCurrentMinute().intValue();
    alarmDetails.timeHour = timePicker.getCurrentHour().intValue();
    alarmDetails.name = edtName.getText().toString();
    alarmDetails.repeatWeekly = chkWeekly.isChecked();
    alarmDetails.setRepeatingDay(AlarmModel.SUNDAY, chkSunday.isChecked());
    alarmDetails.setRepeatingDay(AlarmModel.MONDAY, chkMonday.isChecked());
    alarmDetails.setRepeatingDay(AlarmModel.TUESDAY, chkTuesday.isChecked());
    alarmDetails.setRepeatingDay(AlarmModel.WEDNESDAY, chkWednesday.isChecked());
    alarmDetails.setRepeatingDay(AlarmModel.THURSDAY, chkThursday.isChecked());
    alarmDetails.setRepeatingDay(AlarmModel.FRDIAY, chkFriday.isChecked());
    alarmDetails.setRepeatingDay(AlarmModel.SATURDAY, chkSaturday.isChecked());
    alarmDetails.isEnabled = true;
}
```

Comment: Onclick the intent is fired and states what you said:                                      intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.setType("image/*");
    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);

Comment: I am new still,but it seems to me that the issue maybe with onActivityResult. That is where the text string is being set.I don't know if I need to manage the activity life cycle more with some overides or not. Perhaps @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); is not enough.    Thanks for your help and comments.

Comment: I just realized that this :onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch(item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home: {
        finish();
        break;
    }
    case R.id.action_save_alarm_details: {
        updateModelFromLayout();             the saving is done and this maybe area to fix.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Problem still not resolved startActivityForResult  was called in the onclick method.

Answer (score 0):

Activity and all its content is destroyed when you go back.
You should use startActivityForResult if you want to return back some data.